How to exclude checking black formatter in github actions for folders from the main branch?
I learn Python and I'd like to use GitHub actions, but I have an issue with Black Formatter, because it checks all files in pull-requests (also from the main branch), but I don't need it. I've tried any options I searched for with the command include/exclude, but none works.
What is my problem?
I use this code in my .yml:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      - run: pip install black flake8 isort mypy 
      - run: black --check . || false
      - run: flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
      - run: flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=88 --show-source --statistics
      - run: isort --check-only --profile black . || false
      - run: pip install -r requirements.txt || true
      - run: mypy --install-types --non-interactive . || false

And I tried next commands:
- run: black --check . --verbose --exclude="homework2\" || false

- run: black --check . --verbose --exclude=".\homework2\" || false

- run: black --check . --verbose --exclude="homework2" || false

- run: black --check . --exclude=^/homework2$ || false

- run: black --check . --exclude=.\_python_course\homework1\.py || false

- run: black . --include 'homework1\/.*\.py?$|homework2\/.*\.py?$' --check || false

- run: black . --exclude "/(_python_course/homework1)/" 
- run: black . --check || false 


Did you try regex in single quotes with --exclude flag?
